# How to fill a stacked barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked

I have a df composed of three columns: variant.id, Consequence (variant type) and GeneName.

[image: This is the dataframe.]

Each gene has multiple variants of different types. I need to build a stacked barplot of the top10 genes with the highest number of vairants with the fill of each bar proportional to the number of each variant type. I've managed to build the 'normal barplot' but I could not fill the bar. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Show the code you have for the bar plot you have made so far and an easy way to reproduce your example data using code

Answer (score 0):

```
a_matrix <- table(df$variant.id , df$GeneName)
a_df <- as.data.frame(a_matrix)
a_df <- a_df[with(a_df, order(-Freq)), ]
a_df <- a_df[c(1:10), ]
a_df
```

This might work for to sort and get the first 10 variables.